# How to avoid duplicate bean id in spring when context is loaded from different xml in SPRING

Tags: spring, inversion-of-control, javabeans

I am building an application on jboss server. For that I took a library jar and put in the same server. In that jar, in xml, 1 bean id is used which matched 1 of my bean id.

Due to that in context map, my bean-id is overridden by that jar, when I restarted jboss application.

Is there any way to detect duplicate bean id.
Even if jboss will not start, the same can be tracked.

So, I need the jboss should not come up if such situation happen again.

Is there any possible way to do that??

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use `setAllowBeanDefinitionOverriding(false)` (defined in `AbstractApplicationContext`) to throw a `BeanDefinitionStoreException` instead.